# MySQL asterisk in query

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE phpn_banned_ip 
SET ip_address = SUBSTRING(ip_address, 1, LENGTH(ip_address)-3)&"\*" 
where id=2
```

When running this query in mysql, it zeros out the ip address. Any ideas on how to make the last character an asterisk (*)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to concatenate strings:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ip_address, 1, LENGTH(ip_address)-3), "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(ip_address, 1, LENGTH(ip_address)-3)&"\*" 
----------------------------------------------^---
```

that is invalid syntax you want to use **[concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ip_address, 1, LENGTH(ip_address)-3), "*")
```

so your whole query would look something like this

```
UPDATE phpn_banned_ip 
SET ip_address = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ip_address, 1, LENGTH(ip_address)-3), "*") 
where id=2
```